# SQL - get max result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

Assume there is a table name "test" below:

```
name    value
n1        1
n2        2
n3        3
```

Now, I want to get the name which has the max value, I have some solution below:

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 name 
FROM test 
ORDER BY value DESC
```

**solution 2:**

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test);
```

Now, I hope use join operation to find the result, like

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
INNER JOIN test ON...
```

Could someone please help and explain how it works?

Comment: How do you intend to use the join?

Comment: Solution 1 is not generic as top might not work on all SQL servers.

Comment: Try using Group by clause and filter it with HAVING clause.

Comment: i want to know if join can implement this requirement

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for JOIN then

```
SELECT T.name, T.value
    FROM test T
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT T1.name, T1.value ,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.name ORDER BY T1.value) N
    FROM test T1
    WHERE T1.value IN (SELECT MAX(t2.value) FROM test T2)
)T3 ON T3.N = 1 AND T.name = T3.name
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df45d/9)**

or

```
select  name, value
from
(
  select  name, value,
    row_number() over(order by value desc) rn
  from test
) src
where rn = 1
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df45d/10)**

Comment: you are right, but i want to know if join can do it?

Comment: Is this valid for SQL Server?

Comment: @CarlXu:- Updated my answer. Please check

Comment: is there one solution just simple join test table, test join test on ..., you can add more conditions after on keyword

Comment: @CarlXu:- You can look for the 3rd solution which I have just added!

Answer (score 0):

First, note that solutions 1 and 2 could give different results when *value* is not unique. If in your test data there would be an additional record *('n4', 3)*, then solution 1 would return either *'n3'* or *'n4'*, but solution 2 would return both.

A solution with `JOIN` will need aliases for the table, because as you started of, the engine would say *Ambiguous column name 'name'.*: it would not know whether to take *name* from the first or second occurrence of the *test* table.

Here is a way to complete the `JOIN` version:

```
SELECT    t1.name 
FROM      test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
       ON t2.value > t1.value
WHERE     t2.value IS NULL;
```

This query takes each of the records, and checks if any records exist that have a higher *value*. If not, the first record will be in the result. Note the use of `LEFT`: this denotes an outer join, so that records from *t1* that have no match with *t2* -- based on the `ON` condition -- are not immediately rejected (as would be the case with `INNER`): in fact, we want to reject all the *other* records, which is done with the `WHERE` clause.

A way to understand this mechanism, is to look at a variant of the query above, which lacks the `WHERE` clause and returns the *value*s of both tables:

```
SELECT    t1.value, t2.value  
FROM      test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
       ON t2.value > t1.value
```

On your test data this will return:

```
t1.value t2.value
    1      2
    1      3
    2      3
    3    (null)
```

Note that the last entry would not be there if the join where an `INNER JOIN`. But with the outer join, one can now look for the `NULL` values and actually get those records in the result that would be excluded from an `INNER JOIN`.

Note that this query will give the same result as solution 2 when there are duplicate *value*s. If you want to have also only one result like with solution 1, it suffices to add `TOP 1` after `SELECT`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/462cb/5).

### Alternative with pure INNER JOIN

If you really want an `INNER` join, then this will do it. Again the `TOP 1` is only needed if you have non-unique *value*s:

```
SELECT    TOP 1 t1.name 
FROM      test t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(value) AS value FROM test) t2
       ON t2.value = t1.value;
```

But this one really is very similar to what you did in solution 2. Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/462cb/6) for it.